# How to read BLOB data from a WebSocket which is not an image

Tags: javascript, websocket, coffeescript, blob

I created a WebSocket connection to my webserver to receive some data. However, when I log the event that I receive in the `onmessage` function, then I cannot see the real content of the data.

When I copy the network connection that my Chrome browser v32 opens as a curl command and run it on my OS console, then everything works fine. So I think that somehow my WebSocket setup must be wrong. The `event.data` object is an instance of `Blob`.

**Here is my code** (actually CoffeeScript, but easy to understand)**:**

```
socket = new WebSocket "wss://myserverurl/some-endpoint"

socket.onopen = (event) ->
    console.log 'Connection opened (WebSocket)'

socket.onclose = (event) ->
    console.log 'Connection closed (WebSocket)'
    code = event.code
    reason = event.reason
    wasClean = event.wasClean

socket.onmessage = (event) ->
    console.log JSON.stringify event
```

The `event` that I get:

```
{
    "ports": [],
    "data": {
        "type": "",
        "size": 594
    },
    ...
    "cancelBubble": false,
    "returnValue": true,
    "srcElement": {
        "binaryType": "blob",
        "extensions": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "onerror": null,
        "bufferedAmount": 0,
        "readyState": 1
    },
    "defaultPrevented": false,
    "timeStamp": 1390578698613,
    "cancelable": false,
    "bubbles": false,
    "eventPhase": 2,
    "currentTarget": {
        "binaryType": "blob",
        "extensions": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "onerror": null,
        "bufferedAmount": 0,
        "readyState": 1
    },
    "target": {
        "binaryType": "blob",
        "extensions": "",
        "protocol": "",
        "onerror": null,
        "bufferedAmount": 0,
        "readyState": 1
    },
    "type": "message"
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Ok, I found the solution!** I have to read the data that comes as a `Blob` with a `FileReader`:

```
socket = new WebSocket 'wss://myserverurl/some-endpoint'
socket.binaryType = 'blob'

socket.onopen = (event) ->
    console.log 'Connection opened (WebSocket)'

socket.onclose = (event) ->
    console.log 'Connection closed (WebSocket)'
    code = event.code
    reason = event.reason
    wasClean = event.wasClean

socket.onmessage = (event) ->
    if event.data instanceof Blob
        reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = ->
            console.log reader.result
        reader.readAsText event.data
```

Alternatively, in ES2015:

```js
// Create socket
socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.org/ws");
socket.binaryType = "blob";

// Log socket opening and closing
socket.addEventListener("open", event => {
    console.log("Websocket connection opened");
});
socket.addEventListener("close", event => {
    console.log("Websocket connection closed");
});

// Handle the message
socket.addEventListener("message", event => {
    if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
        reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log("Result: " + reader.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(event.data);
    } else {
        console.log("Result: " + event.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do I receive something like �� �����.(�ǣ��.8��Z@M`�D�� when I try to get reader.result?

Answer (score 11):

You can set tye [`binaryType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/binaryType) of the [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) in JavaScript like:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(url);
socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

Or respectively in CoffeeScript

```
socket = new WebSocket url
socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"
```

And you will get [`ArrayBuffer`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) instead of [`Blob`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). Convert them to [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) by `new Uint8Array(event.data);`

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `Blob.text()`.

```
socket.addEventListener("message", event => {
    // event.data is Blob
    event.data.text().then(txt=>console.log(txt))   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically the best answer I can tell that it's preferred thing to only send string messages in websocket.

So the solution is when sending messages I will highly recommend you to use:

```js
JSON.stringify(data)
```

So, what it does is converting the arrays or objects or any type of data into string

So when you get the data or the message you should converting them back into what status it was on that would be so easy by doing this:

```js
JSON.parse(msg)
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Corrupted 37 into [50, 55] somehow?